# How to set stop loss at previous bar low of long entry?

Tags: pine-script

I would like to set my stop loss at the previous bar low of long entry.

I'm trying value `when(your_condition, low[1], 0)`, but I don't know what "your_condition" is.

Answer (score 0):

`stop` parameter in `strategy.exit()` sets SL price:

> **stop** (series int/float) An optional parameter. Stop loss (requires a specific price).If it is specified, a stop order is placed to exit market position at the specified price (or worse)

Since the function runs on each candle when it closes (and with the data of the candle that just closed) you can set this function so that the `stop` parameter will set `low` as the stop loss price:

```
strategy.exit(id="Close Long", stop=low)
```

Comment: Let’s say i entered trade when the coin was at $2, and let’s say the previous candle low is $1.5. I want my stop loss be at $1.5. But every trade the previous low is different.

Comment: low[1] will give you low of previous candle.